# MySQL Database Modeling for large data sets

Tags: php, mysql, database

A client wants to compile a bunch of data for his customers from a bunch of different sources. I'm building on a PHP/MySQL server architecture. All of my experience is in front-end dev and design, so I'm running into problems with performance, now that there are a lot of data sets.

The performance problem is de-duplication. The main db table stores domains and has four columns: 'id', 'domain_name', and two booleans used to determine whether or not a domain is a possible target for the customers. There is an INDEX on the 'domain_name' column.

I don't want multiple rows for the same domain. The domains arrive in sets of 30,000, and right now I am using:

```
if(!(Domain::find_by_domain($d->n))) {
    // insert into db
}
```

I've also tried:

```
$already_in_db = Domain::list_domains();
if(!in_array($already_in_db)) {
    // insert into db
}
```

There are only about 170,000 domains in the table right now, and both methods already take an extremely long time.

1) Will setting a UNIQUE INDEX on the domain column cause dupes to just be discarded?

2) Are there any other methods to speed up this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your index on the domain name column [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-primary-key.html), then your `INSERT` statements will fail if the domain already exists (you can use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) or [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if you want to change the data in the event of such a collision):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
  DROP INDEX name_of_existing_index,
  ADD  UNIQUE INDEX name_of_existing_index (domain_name);
```

Comment: if the INSERT statements fail, will it cause the loop to stop?

Comment: You can use `INSERT IGNORE` if you don't want MySQL to raise an error.

Comment: is there any advantage/disadvantage to minimizing the number of db calls by creating a string of the domains, then running an INSERT IGNORE on the one string instead of each individual domain?

Comment: Absolutely.  You're [**far** better off](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html) doing `INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_name VALUES (x), (y), (z), ...` than making separate calls.  Better still, if you have a lot of data to insert, you might consider [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) instead.

Comment: Instead of `INSERT IGNORE`, you can use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` to prevent duplicate errors and make the loop continue its work.

Comment: @tpaksu: They will both achieve that, but they otherwise do completely different things (`INSERT IGNORE` **only** ignores duplicates and continues, whereas `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will update duplicate records with new data; besides which, I already discussed `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in my answer).

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. There was something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET id=id` to skip duplicates without updating anything. I remembered that and wrote it. Sorry.